# Calling jQuery function on click

Tags: jquery

Alright, so I've built a function that looks like this...

```
function aboutContent(){
  var about = $(this).data('about'),
      img = $(this).data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(about);
  $('#first-name').html('');
  $('#last-name').html('');
}
```

And I want to call it with a click function, which would look like so...

```
$('.about').click('click', function() {});
```

How would I go about calling the `aboutContent()` function on click?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('.about').click('click', aboutContent)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be:

`$('.about').click(aboutContent);`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
function aboutContent(dis){
  var about = $(dis).data('about'),
     img = $(dis).data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(about);
  $('#first-name').html('');
  $('#last-name').html('');
}
$('.about').click(function() {
    aboutContent(this);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the function reference as the callback instead of a anonymous function

```
$('.about').click('click',aboutContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function aboutContent(element){
  var about = $(element).data('about'),
      img = $(element).data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(about);
  $('#first-name').html('');
  $('#last-name').html('');
}


$('.about').click(function() { aboutContent(this);  });
// alternate ways
// $('.about').click(aboutContent(this));
// $('.about').on('click', aboutContent(this)); // Using on event types
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to call a custom function

one of them

```
$('.about').click(function() {
    aboutContent($(this));
});

function aboutContent(_this){

  var about = _this.data('about'),
  img = _this.data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(about);
  $('#first-name').html('');
  $('#last-name').html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's preety simple.

In simple JavaScript you write the code inside `function(){....}`. In the same way you can implement same in JQuery. Only syntax has been changed. See below code

```
$('.about').click('click', function() {
aboutContent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function like this:

```
$('.about').click(aboutContent);
```

---

Note: $('.about').**click**('**click**',aboutContent); is wrong way to do.

But you do use [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like this:

```
$('.about').on('click', aboutContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this,

```
function aboutContent(){
  var about = $(this).data('about'),
      img = $(this).data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(about);
  $('#first-name').html('');
  $('#last-name').html('');
}

$('.about').click(aboutContent(this));
})
```

your more information related to this refer this link,

[Run jQuery function onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557862/run-jquery-function-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.about').on('click', aboutContent());
```

read about `on` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)