# Send a message when pressing Enter

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
<input type=\"text\" id='MsgToSend" + ToClient + "t" + FromClient + "' onkeypress='ClientOnTyping();' />
```

where the `FromClient` and the `ToClient` are dynamically generated.

JavaScript:

```
function ClientOnTyping() {
  if(e.keyCode==13) {
     // i know i should do this but my problem is what is 'e' in my case how can i specify it ?
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have a look at [this article on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html), especially [this section](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html#link6). It explains how to access the event object, also with inline event handlers.

Comment: if i write e.keyCode==13 is my syntax correct or i should initialize 'e' in some ways ? bcs in tutorial it say : $("#example").keypress(function(e){if(e.KeyCode==13)}); but in my case the keypress function is predefined

Comment: you just answered my question @FelixKling thank you

Comment: I recommend to read the other articles about even handling as well, it should give you a pretty good idea how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach an event listener on the element for `keydown` event.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('MsgToSend');
btn.addEventListerner('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13) {
     // i know i should do this but my problem is what is 'e' in my case how can i specify it ?
    }
});
```

On traditional browsers, you can attach the event handler this way.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('MsgToSend');
btn.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode==13) {
     // i know i should do this but my problem is what is 'e' in my case how can i specify it ?
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, because you saved me typing the exact same answer... (specifically the bit about compensating for IE's interpretation of events.)

Comment: Mmh... if you use `addEventListerner` only, then there is no need to test for `window.event`. Or does IE9 not pass the event object to the handler?

Comment: @FelixKling, I think it does. Isn't it safer this way?

Comment: Browser which implement the W3C `addEventListener` method will surely also pass the event object to the handler, so testing for `window.event` is just unnecessary. It would be different if you used traditional event handlers (i.e. `element.onkeydown = function...`.

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the handler function, `e` is an `event` object created automatically whenever an event fires in the DOM. You need to simply pass it to your handler.

For example:

```
<input ...onkeypress="ClientOnTyping(event);">
```

and

```
function ClientOnTyping(e) {
    ...
}
```

Also, consider using unobtrusive code instead of obtrusive. See [Difference between obtrusive and unobtrusive javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392374/difference-between-obtrusive-and-unobtrusive-javascript) and Starx's answer.

Comment: It must be `onkeypress='ClientOnTyping(event);` and the function must be defined as `function ClientOnTyping(e) {...}`.