# angular restriction to not allow spaces in text field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I do not want a user to enter spaces in a text field.  I don't want it on submit validation but rather - a space will not show up on the text field when they click it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest you write a custom directive which watches keyCode on keydown and take appropriate actions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<input ng-model="field" ng-trim="false" ng-change="field = field.split(' ').join('')" type="text">
```

Update:
To improve code quality you can create custom directive instead. But don't forget that your directive should prevent input not only from keyboard, but also from pasting.

```
<input type="text" ng-trim="false" ng-model="myValue" restrict-field="myValue">
```

Here is important to add ng-trim="false" attribute to disable trimming of an input.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('restrictField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            restrictField: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
          // this will match spaces, tabs, line feeds etc
          // you can change this regex as you want
          var regex = /\s/g;

          scope.$watch('restrictField', function (newValue, oldValue) {
              if (newValue != oldValue && regex.test(newValue)) {
                scope.restrictField = newValue.replace(regex, '');
              }
          });
        }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Why use a `split()` followed by a `join()` if you can use a simple `replace()` instead?

Answer (score 32):

The selected answer is arguably not very [unobtrusive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392446/199712). And if you need to use it in multiple places, you'll end up with duplicated code.

I prefer to prevent the input of spaces using the following directive.

```
app.directive('disallowSpaces', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.bind('input', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, ''));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This directive can be invoked like this:

```
<input type="text" disallow-spaces>
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than the selected answer.

Comment: What would happen if user pasted a string with spaces to an input?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Good question. My original directive probably wouldn't have worked in that case. I replaced my answer with a directive that does account for spaces being pasted in.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about `input` event up until now :). The problem with this solution though is that it places cursor to the end of the string if you are trying to change the text in the middle or in the beginning. What I ended up doing is taking your initial solution + solution from another similar question: https://plnkr.co/edit/BqPFIMDfO2HtlERL9QWk?p=preview. Seems to work

Comment: I have applied this but I type random data and press back space for long time then must letters comes in the input field.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to achieve it without writing directive

`ng-keydown="$event.keyCode != 32 ? $event:$event.preventDefault()"`

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest to use.

Comment: definitely the quickest

Comment: saved me so much time

Comment: what if we copy paste string with empty spaces?

Answer (score 4):

THe directive Jason wrote did not work for me. I had to change return false to: e.preventDefault() like so:

```
app.directive('disallowSpaces', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function($scope, $element) {
            $element.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                if (e.which === 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: failed on pasting the text

Comment: I see. Well this works to prevent special chars, maybe it's adaptable to disallow spaces too. Pasting wont work here: http://kopy.io/KNoU1

Answer (score 2):

This works to prevent entering any special chars including spaces:

```
app.directive('noSpecialChar', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
            if (inputValue == null)
                return ''
            let cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w]|_/gi, '');
            if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return cleanInputValue;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use without jquery

```
 angular.module('app').directive('disallowSpaces', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      maxvalue: '=',
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      $element.bind('keydown', function () {
        function transformer(text) {
          if (text) {
            var transformedInput = text.replace(/ /g, '');
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
            return transformedInput;
          }
          return undefined;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(transformer);
      });
    },
  };
});

// use disallow-spaces

<input type="text" ng-model="name" disallow-spaces />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without writing a directive.

```html
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-keydown="$event.keyCode != 32 ? $event:$event.preventDefault()">
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 9 ,Keycode is not support.

Below code can help you for that.

keyDownHandler(event) {

```
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a directive for this. Tested with Angular v16

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appInputTrim]'
})
/**
 * This directive is used to trim the input value.
 * @author Hakkı Konu
 */
export class InputTrimDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
    trim(value: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = value.trim();
        console.log('value', value);
    }
}
```

usage

```
<input appInputTrim .... />
```