# Angular 4 update input text value via Host listener

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, updates

I have input field in my template and I would like to catch each key press and
update the value in the dom by removinf empty spaces - trim.

I can catch the event and the function I build is working correctly 
but the value in the input text field is not updated accordingly.

```
@HostListener('input', [ '$event.target.value' ])
   input( value ) {
   console.log('value! ' + value);
   value = value.replace(/\s/gi, '');
   console.log('value after trim ' + value);
   return true;
```

}

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `keyup` event and call a method to trim your value. Typescript provides you `trim()` function.

Your html will look like this:

```
<input (keyup)="keyUp($event)">
```

... and define the method in your typescript code:

```
keyUp(event){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.trim();
}
```

Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aJI0NARlOAhpSmJWOrA5?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do it, with less code and the advantage of preventing space from being typed and the caret moving back on space like the accepted solution.

```
<input (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AZyq7DNslD6uu11CXjhq?p=preview)

Credit to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449399/8191975)

Answer (score 1):

When using Angular, try to actually USE Angular.

have `[(ngModel)]="myInput"` and `(ngModelChange)="cleanup()"` now create a function in the ts file:

```
cleanup() {
  this.myInput = this.myInput.replace(/ /g, '');
}
```