# Change the style of a div with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my source I have:
In the style section:

```
<head>
        <style>
               .grayableDiv{background-color:transparent}
        </style>
    </head>

<script>
            function DoGrayEffectIn()
            {
                $('.grayableDiv').css('background-color', 'Gray');

            }
            function DoGrayEffectOut()
            {
                $('.grayableDiv').css('background-color', 'Transparent'); 
            }
       </script>

<div class="grayableDiv" onmouseover ="DoGrayEffectIn" onmouseout="DoGrayEffectOut">
```

But I cannot see the effect when going with the mouse over the div.
What am I doing wrong. Is it possible to mix jquery and javascript in this way?

Comment: I forgot to say I do have jquery in my declarations:
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis `()` to your event handlers so their functions gets called.

Should be `onmouseover ="DoGrayEffectIn()"`, not `onmouseover ="DoGrayEffectIn"`

Stack snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    .grayableDiv {
      background-color: transparent
    }
  </style>
</head>

<script>
  function DoGrayEffectIn() {
    $('.grayableDiv').css('background-color', 'Gray');
  }

  function DoGrayEffectOut() {
    $('.grayableDiv').css('background-color', 'Transparent');
  }
</script>

<div class="grayableDiv" onmouseover="DoGrayEffectIn()" onmouseout="DoGrayEffectOut()">div</div>
```

---

A better practice for attaching JavaScript to the front-end of a website is to separate it from the markup, often referred as [*unobtrusive javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392374/difference-between-obtrusive-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

Stack snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    .grayableDiv {
      background-color: transparent
    }
  </style>
</head>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grayableDiv')
      .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'Gray');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'Transparent');
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="grayableDiv">div</div>
```

Comment: Yes it worked now...Glad to know I can mix javascript with jquery also.

Comment: @user1238784 Of course you can...and FYI, jQuery is built with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function using ()

```
<div class="grayableDiv" onmouseover ="DoGrayEffectIn()" onmouseout="DoGrayEffectOut()">
```

Answer (score 1):

## Another cleaner way without mixing the JavaScript with the Html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".grayableDiv").mouseover(function(){
        $(".grayableDiv").css("background-color", "gray");
    });
    $(".grayableDiv").mouseout(function(){
        $(".grayableDiv").css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
});
</script>
```